# How can I replace part of a cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I downloaded an MS form into Excel.Some cells have text I would like to remove.

For example :"Yes. Please list the PLO in the "Other" box below;Accounting;"

I would like to remove the "Yes. Please list the PLO in the "Other" box below;" but leave the "Accounting" .  The find and replace removes all the text from the cell.

That there is no space before either semicolon. But there is a line break between below and the semicolon. So the exact format is:

```
Yes. Please list the PLO in the "Other" box below
;Accounting;
```

Comment: To aid in a useful answer, how many cells do you need to edit and how often do you need to do this? Also, do you need to do text manipulation in Excel fairly often for other things?

Comment: I will need to do this for about 300 cells.  I send this form out twice a year.  This is the main text manipulation I need to do.

Comment: OK. Is the pattern *always* "some text;keep this;", with the item you want being the last piece of text after a semicolon and it always ends with a semicolon that you don't want to keep?

Comment: Give details about how exactly the texts to replace are organized. I deleted my answer as your comments stipulated other information. Edit your question and add the missing details.

Comment: @Andrew - yes, that is the  exact format.  Except there is always a line break between the "Some Text" and the semicolon.

Comment: @SuzanneWakim In that case, you should be able to do it in two steps when you have the cells you want to affect selected: 1) Find "Yes. Please list the PLO in the "Other" box below;" and replace it with nothng. 2) Find ";" and replace it with nothing.

Comment: Oh, wait, I'm not sure about that line break. Maybe if you copy the "Some Text" and include the space and semicolon and paste that into the "Find what" box.

Comment: @SuzanneWakim I just tested it: you can use a `?` instead of the line break in the Find box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the texts to remove have a space follow by `;` then the texts you want to keep,

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Find and Replace window. Click on the Replace tab.
- Find what: `*`. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Then, type `;`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> allows to enter/type the line break character in the Find what box.
- Replace with: Leave this empty
- Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

**Demo**

[image: Demo find and replace with wildcard]

Comment: It doesn't have a space. And, unfortunately, the content I want to keep also ends with a ;  - I tried this with and without the space. With the space it says it can't be found. Without the space it removes both parts of the content..
I also tried * below and that didn't work either.

Comment: One other piece that may help. There is a line break between the content I want to keep and the content to delete.

Comment: @SuzanneWakim See edit

Comment: I tried that (the * ctrl+J) solution. I get a message that says it can't find that content.  I have a video showing this but don't know how to upload it.

Comment: @SuzanneWakim Based on the edited question, fid what: `*` press Ctrl+J then type `;`

Comment: The error says "We couldn't find anything to replace. Click options for more ways to search.  FYI it's possible the data you're trying to replace is in a protected sheet".  The sheet is not protected. But, I opened a new sheet and pasted the cell contents.  I confirmed that the sheet is not protected.

Comment: Reddy that worked!!!!

Comment: @SuzanneWakim If your question has been successfully answered, please mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: One note on the answer.  You do need to add the ; after ctrl+J for this to work.

Comment: @SuzanneWakim Yes, that was my comment before you stated your error message "we couldn't..."